# Mosaic Dataset Artifacting when out beyond 1:500,000

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, mosaic, mosaic-dataset

See below, I get these areas of white where the datasets aren't loading in certain areas unless I zoom in past 1:500,000.  The data is comprised of a hillshade and an elevation with 50% transparency that I created by running the mosaic tool.  Also, it makes no difference whether I hide one of the two datasets or not.

Is it just that my datasets are too big to handle the amount of data I joined?

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rebuilding the mosaic's overviews, but set the Interpolation to be 'Cubic Convolution'.

The default interpolation has been buggy for years (decades) for overviews, and I've no idea why ESRI still hasn't fixed it.

Depending on the type of data the mosaic represents, other interpolation methods may be more suitable, of course.  Eg, Bilinear.

Comment: This did it, thank you very much!